# Recursive return type function

Tags: c, recursion, return

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int func(int n,int a)// I was trying to sum the values till N value entered by user
{
     
     
    if(n>=a) // for N=2;  n>a sum=3, n>=a sum=5
    {
        return a+func(n,a+1);
    }
    
    
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int n;
    printf("N: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int sum;
    int a=1;
    sum=func(n,a);
    
    printf("1-N Summing: %d",sum);
    
}
```

```
int func(int n,int a)// While return value is not declared, why n is return value?
{
                 //Do I have to declare it always?
     
    if(n>=a) // for N=2;  n>a sum=3, n>=a sum=5
    {
        return a+func(n,a+1);
    }
    else
           return 0;
    
}
```

When N=2, output is 5.My question is why the compiler takes n as a return value while 'if condition' is false.

N,a

2>=1;      1+func(2,2)

```
            1 +2+func(2,3)  here    2\>=3 X  then result must be 1+2=3 according to my understand.

            1  + 2  +2 =5
```

2>1;      1+func(2,2)    here    2>2 X  then result must be '1'

```
          1+ 2=3
```

Comment: In the first example, when `if(n>=a)` is false, the function doesn't return anything. The compiler should warn you of this. "Not all control paths return a value".

Comment: What do you want to happen when `if (condition)` is false?

Comment: See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return : _"Reaching the end of a function returning `void` is equivalent to `return;`. Reaching the end of any other value-returning function is **undefined behavior** if the result of the function is used in an expression"_

Comment: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)